# Airflow Tasks running in parallel

Tags: airflow, airflow-scheduler

I need to run few Airflow tasks in parallel concurrently and if one task got completed successfully, need to call the other task. How can I do that?

```
Ex:
Task A must run first.If successful Task B must run.
If Task A and B are successful, need to run Task C,D,E, F and G in parallel (all starting at the same time) and tasks- C, D,E , F and G are independent of each other.
ONLY if task D is success, task  D1 must be started.
My DAG code looks like below.
task A. >> task B
task B >> [C,D,E,F,G]
D >> D1 

Thanks in advance!
```

Comment: What is your question/problem?

Comment: @EladKalif - I'm not sure whether my above example is correct? Take D should run only after successful completion of task B. And after successful completion of task D, I want to run D1. Thanks!

Comment: Make sure your Executor in airflow.cfg is set to LocalExecutor or Celery Executor. It shouldnt be SequentialExecutor(doesnt allow parallelism).

Answer (score 0):

Your task ordering looks good, although it is sloppily written.

If your tasks are not running concurrently make sure you've set the [concurrency setting](https://airflow.apache.org/docs/apache-airflow/stable/_api/airflow/models/dag/index.html?highlight=concurrency#airflow.models.dag.DAG) to more than 1 when instantiating your DAG.

Comment: Thanks Much! I'm new to Airflow. Could you let me know how I can improve my DAG? Am I missing anything ? Appreciate your suggestions for improvement!

Answer (score 0):

Your definition is perfectly fine to what you described (other than syntax issues).

Note that parallelism depends on your executor and available resources and you can not force "start at the same time"

```
B >> [C,D,E,F,G]
```

means that `C,D,E,F,G` can run in parallel. This statement has no control over which will run first or even if they will run in parallel. The statement just say that they can. Should you want to define order of execution in between them then you need to change the dependency.